Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в данном случае?_

У него большой опыт(,) и он работал в достаточно крупных компаниях.

Подобные формулировки встречал в обоих вариантах. Склоняюсь к варианту с запятой.

Правильно:
У него большой опыт, и он работал в достаточно крупных компаниях.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Решение задачи следует из грамматического анализа. Это ССП, здесь две предикативные основы, союз И.
Первое предложение в составе ССП двусоставное, эллиптического вида: дополнение + подлежащее. Второе предложение двусоставное: он работал.
Розенталь, § 6.1 Тире в неполном предложении.
 При отсутствии паузы в эллиптических предложениях тире не 
 ставится: А в доме стук, ходьба… (Гр.); Вдруг передо мною 
 рытвина глубокая (Л.);

В ССП отсутствует общий элемент, нет оснований для непостановки запятой.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Но почему же пишут без запятой?  Этот вопрос более интересный.
С точки зрения грамматики, пользователи могут неправильно определить предикативные основы. С точки зрения семантики, можно увидеть общую тему в отнесении двух сообщений к одному лицу. Но  предложения в данном случае неоднородны, зависимы: второе предложение дополняет содержание первого: большой опыт, в том числе в крупных компаниях.
Но если взять другой общий элемент, то два предложения можно считать однородными, например: Он хороший специалист: у него большой опыт и он работал в достаточно крупных компаниях.

ВЫВОД

Для отсутствия запятой в ССП необходимы два условия: наличие общего элемента и однородность/независимость предложений.
Решение можно проверить интонационно: если не ставится запятая, то все сообщение произносится  без четко обозначенной паузы в одну фонетическую фразу.
